# Insert NULL DateTime with SQL Server stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I have written a SQL Server stored procedure that includes a `DateTime` parameter. This parameter could be null or contain a valid date value.

So the definition of my variable in my procedure is below:

```
@piPurchase_Date DATETIME = NULL
```

From C# I add the parameter as follows:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@piPurchase_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value=datePurchaseIssueDate.Checked ? datePurchaseIssueDate.Value : SqlDateTime.Null;
```

So far all seems OK but when I call the Update method on the DataAdaptor I receive the following error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlDateTime to a DateTime.

Any ideas?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and C#4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can use `String.Empty` or `""` and this is converted to a `NULL` `DateTime` value.

Comment: have you just tried passing in null `paramter.Value = datePurchaseIssueDate.Checked ? (DateTime?) datePurchaseIssueDate.Value : null;`

Comment: You might want to try replacing the `null` section with `DbNull.Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - use `DBNull.Value` in C#:

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@piPurchase_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value = datePurchaseIssueDate.Checked ? datePurchaseIssueDate.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

to pass a NULL to a SQL Server stored procedure

Comment: this would generate error Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DBNull'